# How to call PostgreSQL function with user-defined type parameter using JdbcTemplate in SpringBoot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to call the stored procedure from the SpringBoot app. The procedure has a single parameter of custom-defined type.

```sql
create type t_item as (
  name text,
  count integer
);
```

The procedure just takes the data passed in and iterates through, performing some actions.

```sql
create procedure process_items (
    p_items t_item[]
)
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   v_item t_item;
begin
   foreach v_item IN ARRAY p_items
   loop
      -- do something with v_item
   end loop;
end
$$
```

Then in the SpringBoot app, I have service from where I want to call the procedure. I thought I would use JdbcTemplate. But I don't know how to bind the parameter. Is that even possible with custom-defined types?

```kotlin
@Service
class MyService {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate

    ...

    fun processItems(items: ItemModel[]) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(
            "call process_items(?)",
            // ??? how to bind the parameter using ObjectMapper
            // or any other method?
        )
    }
    
    ...
}
```